# How to resolve Window error[3] in a Python script?

Tags: python, directory, runtime-error

In my script I am listing files stored in a directory using as follows:

```
 path ="D:/name/hello/school"
 files = os.listdir(path)
```

Now, when I executed it earlier it worked all fine but now it suddenly it is throwing

> Window [Error 3]

Is there an alternate way to list all the files within a directory?

I have also tried `os.walk(path)` but it also did not work as I am getting a *StopIteration* error.

Comment: Is that all the code you are trying to run? Also we could benefit if your add the whole error trace!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer to your question has been already discussed in these two questions:

1. [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python) - they present some alternative ways of listing files in Windows using python. They've mentioned the `glob` module which might be helpful.
2. [Python WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the file specified when trying to rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220280/python-windowserror-error-3-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-tr) - this one applies to the Error 3.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To list all files in a directory.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(/path/to/directory) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
```

To list all files and folders in a directory

```
os.listdir("/path/to/directory")
```

To find all files in a directory recursively

```
all_files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
  for filename in filenames:
    all_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```